# Vite with react not working for basename with react-router-dom after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, vite

I am using `react: 18.2.0` with `vite: 4.4.0`. And for routing using `react-router-dom: 6.14.1`.

I have to host my app to a path `/packers`. The project is working fine in development environmet. But when build it and try to serve with `express.js: 4.18.2` it serves the html only, not the assets. If I build the front-end without the `basename` it works fine.

Now, my question is why is is happening only in build and how to fix it?

Here are the files I have in my project:

main.jsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "./routes/routes";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

routes.jsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter, redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "../Layout/Main";
import Home from "../pages/Home";
import Login from "../pages/Login";
import Recovery from "../pages/Recovery";
import Signup from "../pages/Signup";
import ErrorPage from "../pages/ErrorPage";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Main />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/login",
        element: <Login />,
      },
      {
        path: "/reset",
        element: <Recovery />,
      },
      {
        path: "/signup",
        element: <Signup />,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes, {
  basename: "/packers"
});
```

vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()],
  base: '/packers'
});
```